# Build configurations in Zerobrane Studio, is it possible?

Tags: zerobrane

Is there a way to have/use/implement build configurations in zerobrane studio?
I use corona and my current IDE is lua glider. Although the lua glider project has been dead for almost two years, I still use the IDE because it has build configurations. Is there anyway to have/achieve the same functionality in zerobrane studio?

To clarify, with glider's build configurations i can 
1- auto insert code to the top of main.lua before build (example: isFreeVersion = false; OR isFreeVersion = true)
2- merge folders or copy contents from one folder into another before build (example: have two similar projects using common code; i put these code files in a common folder and copy its content to the project folder at build; that way i only edit these code files once)

Many thanks,
Luay

Comment: Do you have details on how it's configured? This is most certainly possible, but I wonder if a couple of event callbacks can be added to simplify the process.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko: unfortunately, I don't. LuaGlider is based on Netbeans, so i'm guessing it is either in the default editor or a plugin. I'm happy to provide further details if you tell me what I should look for. Thanks

Comment: I don't mean how it's implemented; I mean how you configure it as the user. I couldn't find any details in their documentation.